# Mysql referencing the same column from table 1 as foreign key to two columns in table two

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two mysql tables with the second one having foreign key references to the first one.  The first table is as follows:

1st Table name: treeview

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | name      | text      | parent_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | BrandTree | BrandTree | 0         |
|  2 | TShirt    | TShirt    | 1         |
|  3 | ManForce  | ManForce  | 2         |
|  4 | PayTM     | PayTM     | 2         |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am using this table to generate a jstree.  And my second table is as follows:

2nd table name: annotations:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| ann_id | imagename                           | locationName | brandname |
+--------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
|      1 | 95-20180527-190018-205342-00002.jpg |            2 |         3 |
|      2 | 95-20180527-190018-205342-00005.jpg |            2 |         4 |
+--------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

In the second table, the locationName and brandname have foreign key references to first table id column.  I am using the following code to retrieve the table:

```
select annotations.imagename, treeview.name, treeview.text 
from annotations 
inner join treeview on treeview.id = annotations.locationName 
and inner join treeview on treeview.id = annotations.brandname;
```

The above code provides a Empty set.

Can I have the id column from table 1 as foreign key for two columns in table 2?  How do i fetch in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's doing one join, twice

```
select annotations.imagename, tv1.name, tv2.name 
from annotations 
inner join treeview tv1 on tv1.id = annotations.locationName 
inner join treeview tv2 on tv2.id = annotations.brandname;
```

I think, haven't got mysql handy

Comment: Aye the alias made it do two joins. The way you had it it was doing one join which would only work for rows where location and brand ids are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use two join with thetreeview table  one for each column that refer  to the table annotations

```
    select annotations.imagename, tv1.name, tv1.text, t2.name, tv2.text
    from annotations 
    inner join treeview tv1 on tv1.id = annotations.locationName 
    inner join treeview tv2  on tv2.id = annotations.brandname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different alias names for `treeview` tables that you have used twice. And not required `and` before `inner join...`.

**Query**

```
select `t1`.`imagename`, `t2`.`name`, `t3`.`text`
from `annotations` as `t1` 
inner join `treeview` as `t2`
on `t2`.`id` = `t1`.`locationName`
inner join `treeview` as `t3` 
on `t3`.`id` = `t1`.`brandname`;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aa0150/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Select a.imagename,t1.name,t2.name from annotations a,treeview t1,treeview t2 where a.locationName=t1.id && a.brandname=t2.id;